# Python imports are not working even i installed them

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am importing following things in python but it is showing errors, even i installed those using pip

Imports -

```
import speech_recognition as sr  # importing speech recognition package from google api
# from pygame import mixer
import playsound    # to play saved mp3 file
from gtts import gTTS   # google text to speech
import os   # to save/open files
import wolframpythonalpha # to calculate strings into formula, its a website which provides api, 100 times per day
from selenium import webdriver  # to control browser operations
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from io import BytesIO
from io import StringIO
```

Errors -

[image: Errors]

Comment: Those aren't really errors. Did you try to run the code?

Comment: Yes, actually i used them in code, so code wont run

Comment: No, no, I mean did you actually run the code with python

Comment: Yes i run, error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'

Comment: Are you working with environment? If having more than one Python, did you make sure you install your libraries with `python3 -m pip install—user Packages`?

Comment: I only have python 2.7

Comment: I installed python 3 and ran the command you gave and i got this - ```Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/3.7'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create your import sequence on a [google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com)

I found that several of the packages needed to be pip installed.

```
!pip install SpeechRecognition
!pip install playsound
!pip install gTTS
!pip install wolframalpha
!pip install selenium
```

note the "!"  in front of the pip is required to install packages on the google colab platform.

I also could not find a the "wolframpythonalpha" package you referenced but I did find wolframalpha

Once installed most everything else imports...

```
import speech_recognition
import playsound
import os   # to save/open files
import wolframalpha
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from io import BytesIO
from io import StringIO
```

Comment: it gives me this error - ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for install```

Comment: @AshvinBhagat can you try this first `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

`python -m pip install wheel` and then try what @Timothy suggested?

Comment: @AshvinBhagat  my guess is that you are running on MacOS.  I have endured a lot of pain trying to run Python installing different packages and versions of python on on my Mac until I learned about virtual environments. If you are just trying out new things, I think the google colab notebook is awesome and encourage you to give it a try.

Comment: None of them worked for me, but when i switched ti PyCharm from VS code then everything is solved

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the another answer given in this question works for you but none of the things worked for me, i don't know why but when i switched to a IDE named PyCharm, everything works fine, PyCharm automatically installed those things and they are working now.